# View return of a function in ASP.NET View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have written a function that returns an int. Now I would like to use it in my View, but I don't know how I can integrate the function or the return of the function in the HomeController.

Comment: If you can provide your code, it would be easy to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ViewBag.Number = yourFunction();
```

in the view you can use

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Number</h1>
```